# Displaying and editing multivalued attribute?

Tags: web-app, tables, grid, data

I don't know if "multivalued attribute" sounds good but I will try to explain my problem. I work on a web app and I have a list of users. Each user has a number (from 0 to ≈100) of "codes" related to him. Each code can be related to one or many users.

I have to display the list of users and the codes for each user. I also have to allows the administrators to edit the links between the codes and the users.

These requirements make the UI/UX a bit complex for me and I don't know how to do this. I thought about the following wireframes but I think it could be better.

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fNOg1o.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

One table with the list of users with a button displaying another table with all the related codes. Then I thought about a textaera allowing a raw editing of these codes (the administrators should be able to edit multiple codes in a row).

The main difficulty is how to edit/delete all these codes. I don't like the textaera but I don't know how to do it better.

These views are for administrators only (around 4 users) so they don't have to be "beautiful" or very "user-friendly" and can't take a lot of my time. But administrators have to easily know the codes related to the users and quickly edit them if needed.

Answer (score 2):

Your example solution requires the admin to remember a list of relevant codes & what they mean/who they are linked to. I don't know about your specific users, but most people are not very good at recalling number codes.

If the list of code is short enough, consider displaying a table of these code.

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fonHVm.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, when pressing "show codes" you'll only see the codes associated with that particular user. Therefor, displaying the name of the user is superfluous. Showing the codes in a table and then showing the codes again in a textfield for the second time is superfluous too.

My suggestion would be for a row of input fields for every code. (or multiple rows) The input can be easily changed and it will be easier for the admin to find the right code.

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fAenCI.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

Comment: I think the list display was better for the user - it's easier to scan down a list to look for a particular code, than hunt through a grid.

Answer (score 1):

Unless users should be allowed to arbitrarily create new codes through the same interface you'll want the interface to provide the available codes to the user, either a full list of all available codes or through a full or partial auto-complete functionality (like assigning tags to questions here in the stack exchange.)

Unless there is need for extended description or explanation of the options, a full table as nightning suggests is probably too much.

Multi-select boxes are pretty much designed for this. If there is a short description or mnemonic available use that instead of or in addition to the straight code.

With a small number of codes a straight multiselect list is reasonable.

Beyond some threshold you should offer some filtering of available codes and/or change the filter box into a search box and dynamically fetch the options that match.

With a great number of available codes separating the display of the selected codes and the currently displayed options becomes useful. In this example the 6 selected items will show regardless of scroll position or filtering on the options list.

[image]